# PHP regex, preg_replace_callback, failing with 2 possible matches in 1 string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I was playing around with this very basic class to learn more about regexes. What I wanted to achieve is to grab the content from a testview file, grab the string exactly between {{EACH slides}} and  {{#EACH}}. The regex now present in the class did just that, plus the variable name in the opening tag. I then wanted to use that string to loop it with the right variable and put it back in place.

But when I use 2 EACH-loops in my view instead of 1, it fails badly. 
The preg_replace_callback() will match the first opening-tag, and the last closing-tag of the second loop, and give a string something like this:

```
"htmlbalalbal {{#EACH}} more htmlblabla {{EACH newsitems}} htmlblalblabla"
```

From:

```
<div class="rows-container">
{{each slides}}
    <div class="row flex-wrap" data-id="{{id}}">
    </div>
{{#each}}
</div>
<div class="rows-container">
{{each blogposts}}
    <div class="row flex-wrap" data-id="{{id}}">
    </div>
{{#each}}
```

I've been trying the change the regex for quite some time now, and I'm starting to see more and more logic in it... but I have yet not solved my problem. Is it even possible to go down this path? or do I need another solution for scanning multiple EACH loops in my testfile? 
I will probably soon be using some framework, but I like doing this stuff when I'm bored during the weekends...

```
class Aclass{

    private $each = '~\{\{each ([^{]*)\}\}([^*]*)\{\{\#each\}\}~i';

    private $current_file_content = "";
    private $testviews = ['/testview.php'];

    private $views;

    function __construct($views){
        $this->views = $views; //not in use
        $this->start();
   }

   private function start(){
        foreach($this->testviews as $file){
            $this->current_file_content = file_get_contents(ROOT.$file);
            $this->scan_each();
        }
   }

   private function scan_each(){
       $result = preg_replace_callback($this->each, [$this, '_each'], $this->current_file_content);
   }


    private function _each($matches){
        foreach($matches as $match){
            var_dump(htmlspecialchars($match));
            echo '<br><br>';
        }
    }
```

Edit:16-5
So, I've been going further.. its working great, but it doesn't cover an each inside another each. It's a situation like this, which I think might be useful in the future:

```
{{each attributes}}
<label>{title}</label>
<select name="{key}" id="{key}" class="select">
    <option value="0" selected>choose an option</option>
    {{each values}}
        <option value="{id}" {selected}>{title}</option>
    {{#each}}
</select>
{{#each}}
```

I've been wondering if there is a way to cover it in 1 regex, and then if the function that processes the outer each-loop sees another each inside, it will finish that 1 first. I'm totaly willing to build the functions myself, but it would be awesome to get some tips. Would you recommend separating the regex? to find {{each X}} and {{#each}} and fix it another way in php, or fix the answered Regex to be able to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex can be fixed as

```
'~{{each\s+([^{}]*)}}(.*?){{#each}}~is'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FWMsGE/1).

The main point here is that `[^*]` you used in your pattern matches any character but `*` while you need to match any 0+ characters between one string and the other. It can be achieved with `.*?` and `s` modifier.

**Details**:

- `{{each` - a literal substring
- `\s+` -  1+ whitespaces
- `([^{}]*)` - Group 1: zero or more chars other than `{` and `}`
- `}}` - a literal `}}` substring
- `(.*?)`  - Group 2: any 0+ chars, as few as possible (due to the lazy `*?` quantifier
- `{{#each}}` - a literal `{{#each}}` substring.

Comment: Tnx! I will have to look into this tomorrow, I want to fully understand it before I continue, but it seems to work

Comment: One remark: if after `{{each` there may be `{` or `}` before the closest `}}`, you should replace `([^{}]*)` with `(.*?)`.

Comment: Tnx! I have implemented it now. Can do each with 3 types of arrays, if, else if and else, vars and superglobals. But the problem with my patterns is that I can't build each-loops within another each loop, and no ifs within ifs etc. I'm afraid I have to separate the opening and closing patterns, and go a different way. But for my school projects.. if it works it works lol.

Comment: Or is there a way to fix it with recursive regexes? xD haven't looked into that yet

Comment: Recursion is not "free", it is not obvious and supports a certain (though substantial) recursion level number. If you share specific string I could help, but the regex might get unwieldly then.

Comment: ive eddited my question to make it more readable, I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Check [this PHP demo](http://ideone.com/ctOChe) and [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZRaFVN/1).

Comment: Tnx a bunsh! I think I will try to build two separate callback functions instead of a recursive 1, to make it more readable and easier to retrieve the vars from the data array. Will look into it later this week!

Comment: Or actualy, I might drop the second match and capture this from the content of the first match. Otherwise I might not be able to track which each is a child or a parent when I get matches from the whole view

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with this one:

`private $each = '~{{each\s+(.+?)}}(.+?){{#each}}~is';`

[RegEx101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/k3z9t6/2)